# Beautiful Soup: Parsing only one element

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I keep running into walls, but feel like I'm close here.

HTML block being harvested:

```
div class="details">
   <div class="price">
   <h3>From</h3>
   <strike data-round="true" data-currency="USD" data-price="148.00" title="US$148 ">€136</strike>
   <span data-round="true" data-currency="USD" data-price="136.00" title="US$136 ">€125</span>
</div>
```

I would like to parse out the "US$136" value alone (span data). Here is my logic so far, which captures both 'span data' and 'strike-data:

```
price = item.find_all("div", {"class": "price"})
        price_final = (price[0].text.strip()[8:])
        print(price_final)
```

Any feedback is appreciated:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`price` in your case is a `ResultSet` - list of `div` tags having `price` class. Now you need to locate a `span` tag inside every result (assuming there are multiple prices you want to match):

```
prices = item.find_all("div", {"class": "price"})
for price in prices:
    price_final = price.span.text.strip()
    print(price_final)
```

---

If there is only once price you need to find:

```
soup.find("div", {"class": "price"}).span.get_text()
```

or with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select_one("div.details div.price span").get_text()
```

Note that, if you want to use `select_one()`, install the latest `beautifulsoup4` package:

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```